# Sticky Content Behavior Limited to First Tab with Vuesticky-kit and Bootstrap Vue's b-tabs

Tags: vue.js, sticky

In my project, I'm integrating the vuesticky-kit library alongside Bootstrap Vue's b-tabs component. The vuesticky-kit library can be found at: https://github.com/imfaber/vue-stickykit.

Here's the code snippet I'm currently working with:

```
<b-tabs>
  <b-tab v-for="tab in tabs">
    <div>
      <div v-stick-parent>Scrollable sticky content for the table</div>
      <b-table></b-table>
    </div>
  </b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

The issue I'm encountering revolves around the sticky behavior within this setup. While the sticky behavior functions correctly within the first tab, it fails to persist when switching to other tabs. Interestingly, if I return to the first tab after navigating to others, the sticky behavior is once again operational.

I have made attempts to address this issue by utilizing the recalc and tick functions provided by the Vuesticky-kit library. The library's documentation, available at https://leafo.net/sticky-kit/, contains detailed information about these functions.